# order Search result by similarity

Tags: php, mysql

On the same page i have two Search result. The first one automatically generated from the page prior to the current page. I have a field Called Brand Name I want the second search order to be based on the value or text on the first search
.For example, if Brand= X all X brands to be at the top the second search

```
 $rbrand = $row [Brand_name] // Brand name from first search result
```

I tried this to order the second search result

```
 SELECT * 
  FROM tablename 
ORDER 
    BY IF(Brand_Name LIKE '%$rbrand%',0,1)
```

Comment: What is the variable of the second search result?

Comment: @Samir For the second one i use the field Name `Brand_Name`

Comment: Still you requirement is unclear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ORDER BY (Brand_Name='X') DESC,Brand_Name
```

This will put the rows that have Brand_Name='X This First' first, then will proceed to order everything else based on other.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways on accomplishing this.

You could use `CASE, WHEN, THEN`

```
SELECT CASE WHEN Brand_Name LIKE '%$rbrand%' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS Brand_Sort, Brand_Name
FROM tablename
ORDER BY Brand_Sort
```

Or a `UNION` for example

```
SELECT Brand_Name 
FROM tablename
WHERE Brand_Name LIKE '%$rbrand%'
UNION
SELECT Brand_Name 
FROM tablename
WHERE Brand_Name NOT LIKE '%$rbrand%'
```